# ffmpeg max_volume Positive Decibels?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

Does the ffmpeg's `max_volume` parameter return positive values or does it max out at `0`?

I'm seeing multiple files returning `0` for the maximum volume but the volume levels aren't the same. Some have deafening blips in them which I'm trying to detect and remove.

Example ffmpeg output:

```
frame=19323 fps=1143 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:12:52.92 bitrate=N/A    
video:1812kB audio:144184kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.000015%
n_samples: 73822208
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7f77e0] mean_volume: -22.6 dB
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7f77e0] max_volume: 0.0 dB
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7f77e0] histogram_0db: 8169
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7f77e0] histogram_1db: 388
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7f77e0] histogram_2db: 531
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7f77e0] histogram_3db: 2389
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7f77e0] histogram_4db: 5039
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7f77e0] histogram_5db: 12128
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7f77e0] histogram_6db: 24978
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7f77e0] histogram_7db: 48077
```

When using:

```
ffmpeg -i /var/www/CDNFiles/Video_1Web.mp4 -af "volumedetect" -f null /dev/null/ 2>&1
```

... or is ffmpeg the wrong tool for this? I have mp4 videos files encoded with the h264 codec.

Thanks.

Comment: Try with `-af astats=reset=1:metadata=1,ametadata=print:file=volume.log` and check volume.log for `lavfi.overall.RMS_level / peak`

Comment: I don't need to cast it to a file right? `ffmpeg -i /var/www/CDNFiles/Video_1Web.mp4 -af "astats=reset=1:metadata=1,ametadata=print" -f null /dev/null/ 2>&1` should work? That's not bringing back any `lavfi` or `peak` values. I'll update the question with the response if that is correct usage.

Comment: Replace `volume.log` with `-` for console output. But it'll zip by.

Comment: That's returning `At least one output file must be specified` for `ffmpeg -i /var/www/CDNFiles/Video_1Web.mp4 -af "astats=reset=1:metadata=1,ametadata=print:file=/home/chris/volume.log"` or `ffmpeg -i /var/www/CDNFiles/Video_1Web.mp4 -af "astats=reset=1:metadata=1,ametadata=print:file=-"`

Comment: You need to keep the output i.e. `-f null /dev/null` Replace volume.log in my filter statement with `-`

Comment: Okay, that gives `Error opening filters!` with `ffmpeg -i /var/www/CDNFiles/Video_1Web.mp4 -af astats=reset=1:metadata=1,ametadata=print:file=- -f null /dev/null/ 2>&1`

Comment: Not a linux user, so can't debug, but you should not redirect stderr.

Answer (score 3):

"max_volume" cannot be greater than 0.

According to [libavfilter/af_volumedetect.c](//github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/802d94c/libavfilter/af_volumedetect.c):

```c
av_log(ctx, AV_LOG_INFO, "max_volume: %.1f dB\n", -logdb(max_volume * max_volume));
```

So, to return positive as you request, "logdb" needs to return a negative
number. Here is logdb:

```c
#define MAX_DB 91

static inline double logdb(uint64_t v)
{
    double d = v / (double)(0x8000 * 0x8000);
    if (!v)
        return MAX_DB;
    return -log10(d) * 10;
}
```

If "d" is greater than 1, "logdb" will return negative:

```c
$ awk 'BEGIN {print -log(2) / log(10) * 10}'
-3.0103
```

To get "d", over 1, "max_volume" needs to be greater than 0x8000. Can
"max_volume" be greater than 0x8000? No, it cannot:

```c
max_volume = 0x8000;
while (max_volume > 0 && !vd->histogram[0x8000 + max_volume] &&
                         !vd->histogram[0x8000 - max_volume])
    max_volume--;
```

If you do not want to re-encode the file, you can use AacGain as long as the
file has an audio stream:

```c
aacgain -k -r -s s -m 10 file
```

Or if you just want to analyse:

```c
aacgain -s s file
```

Info:

```
-k - automatically lower Track/Album gain to not clip audio
-r - apply Track gain automatically (all files set to equal loudness)
-s s - skip (ignore) stored tag info (do not read or write tags)
-m <i> - modify suggested gain by integer i
```

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try the `aacgain` option out yet but will look at it. Thanks.